# How to drop the end of a request?

Tags: networking

In order to reproduce a bug hapened in production environment between two vm I'm looking after a way to drop the end of a HTTP communication.

Is there some unix tools able to drop last TCP packets of a network session? Or do you know other way to achieve my goal?

Comment: One starting point might be `iptables`. But what is your definition of "last TCP packets"?

Comment: I can get an estimation of the total length of the TCP stream. If I could DROP a TCP session from the 100000th bit for instance it could do the job @roaima

Comment: I don't know any way to do that. I know it would be possible to drop packets from client to server that contained FIN (but mind HTTP keepalive streams).

Answer (score 2):

As roaima suggested, you can use iptables to do this. I would try the following:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i <interface> -p tcp --dport <port_used> -m state --state ESTABLISHED -m nth --counter 0 --every 100000 --packet 100000 -j DROP
```